# prove on induced and restricted representation

Tags: representation-theory, characters

can anybody please help me with this question? I have huge trouble even just start it.

Let H, K be subgroups of G and HK=G. If $\psi$ is a character of H, show that $(\psi^G)_K = (\psi_{H \cap K})^K$.

So basically $\psi^G = Ind^G_H(W)$, so W should be just H-module, and $(\psi^G)_K$ is just restricted to K. I have trouble to even just decompose this expression above. Can anybody please give me a hand? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the character of an induced representation in terms of the character of the original representation?

Comment: I only know character of an induced representation is sum of character of original representation evaluated on conjugates. Am I right? Sorry I probably didn't say it well as I can't type in latex in comment window here.

Comment: Yes, that is the formula I mean. The result follows by simply plugging the two representations into it.

Comment: Sure, but, if you don't mind, could you please tell me how to manipulate that formula a bit please? Honestly, even if I got formula right in front of me, I just have trouble understanding where are all the elements in, the notation feels really annoying. Can you please give me a very quick small example? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that it does take a bit more than just plugging into the formula. Here are the calculations.

Let $T\subseteq H$ be given such that $G = \bigcup_{t\in
T}tK$ is a disjoint union. For $x\in K$ we have $$\varphi^G(x) =
\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{g\in G}\varphi^{\circ}(gxg^{-1}) =
\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{t\in T}\sum_{z\in
K}\varphi^{\circ}(tzxz^{-1}t^{-1}) = \frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{t\in
T}\sum_{z\in K}\varphi^{\circ}(zxz^{-1})$$ $$=
\frac{1}{|H|}|T|\sum_{z\in K}\varphi^{\circ}(zxz^{-1}) =
\frac{1}{|H|}|G:K|\sum_{z\in K}\varphi^{\circ}(zxz^{-1}) =
\frac{|G|}{|H||K|}\sum_{z\in K}\varphi^{\circ}(zxz^{-1})$$ $$=
\frac{1}{|H\cap K|}\sum_{z\in K}\varphi^{\circ}(zxz^{-1})  =
(\varphi_{H\cap K})^K(x)$$

Where $\varphi^{\circ}(h) = \varphi(h)$ if $h\in H$ and $0$ otherwise.